# MYSQL for a 3 part search (Online Audio Software) - Search - Genre - & Catagory

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Project website that I am stuck in and although I can create a relatively working search engine using LIKE Wildcards , I cannot build a Professional and accurate Search Engine that would cover all 3 optional criteria's (Title , Genre & Category). And also show Relevant results if none are at first found.

If I select All 3 Criteria's at once I can often get a negative result even though there is a relative result to be found.

(I am really struggling to explain myself it is so complicated for me to get my head around)

The best way to show you is to show you my code.

Hopefully somebody will be able to advise me the best way to approach the search engine.

My intentions are to have a search that will show the correct results regardless of the order of the criteria and if no results are found then to show Relevant or similar results.

It has become quite a challenge.

My attempts at resolving the issue have been different formats of the query including LIKE wildcards. and no matter which way round i format i find problems in the search results.

Basically. if anybody can provide a query that they think would work, as in will produce results no matter what, I  will try it.

My main problem is when there is no results found it is not showing the next best relevant set of results.

I have been going around in circles going through different queries and upto yet have not hit the nail on the head (so to say)

```
if (!empty($search)) { 
    
    if (!empty($genre)){$query="select * from audiolovedb WHERE MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ('$search') AND (`genre`) LIKE '$genre' ORDER BY `title` LIKE '$search%' DESC, `title` limit $amount "; }
    else {$query="select * from audiolovedb WHERE MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ('$search') AND (`catagory`) LIKE '$catagory' ORDER BY `title` LIKE '$search%' DESC, `title` limit $amount "; }

    }else { 
           if (!empty($genre)){$query="select * from audiolovedb WHERE (`genre`) LIKE '$genre%' ORDER BY `genre` LIKE '$genre' DESC, `genre` limit $amount "; }
           else {$query="select * from audiolovedb WHERE (`catagory`) LIKE '$catagory%' ORDER BY `catagory` LIKE '$catagory' DESC, `catagory` limit $amount ";}
          }

$stat=$db->prepare($query);
$stat->execute(array());    
$count = $stat->rowCount();
```

And the form that sends the GET data

```
<form method="GET" action='index.php'>   <!--Ends further Down-->

<select id='genregrab' name='genre' class='menusmall'>
   <optgroup label='Genre'>
   <option value="">All Genres</option>
   <option value="House">House</option>
   <option value="House">House</option>
   <option value="Hard House">Hard House</option>
   <option value="Tech House">Tech House</option>
   <option value="Deep House">Deep House</option>   
   <option value="Future House">Future House</option>
   <option value="Tribal House">Tribal House</option>
   <option value="Tropical House">Tropical House</option>
   <option value="EDM">EDM</option>
   <option value="DnB">DnB</option>
   <option value="Drum and Bass">Drum And Bass</option>
</select>



        <select id='catagorygrab' name='catagory' class='menusmall'>
            <optgroup label='Software'>
            <option value="Windows">Windows Pc</option>
            <option value="Mac OSX">Mac OSX</option>

            <optgroup  label='Audio'>
            <option value="Samples" >Samples</option>
            <option value="Presets">Presets</option>
            <option value="Additional Libraries">Libraries</option>

            <option value="SFX">SFX</option>
            <option value="Vocals">Vocals</option>
            <option value="Sound">Sound FX</option>
            <option value="Film">Film/TV/Game</option>

            <optgroup label='Project'>
            <option value="MiDi">MiDi</option>
            <option value="Projects">Projects</option>
            <option value="Templates">Templates</option>

            <optgroup label='Learning'>
            <option value="Video">Video</option>
            <option value="eBooks">eBooks</option>

            <optgroup label='Addons'> 
            <option value="Skins">Skins</option>
            <option value="Extras">Extras</option> 

        </select>


<!-- add amount selected previously to amount box -->

<?php $genre = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $genre), 0, 1)); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('catagorygrab').value = '<?php echo $catagory ?>'
    document.getElementById('genregrab').value = '<?php echo $genre ?>'
</script>


<!--- search bar --->
<div class="search-input">
    <input id='search' type="text" name='search' placeholder="Random Products" value="<?php echo $search ?>">
</div>
                                                                                
    <div class="search-btn">                                                                                    
        <button><i class="lni lni-search-alt"></i></button>                                                                                     
    </div>                                                                                  

</form>
```

Comment: for starters, you need to fix your sql injection vulnerabilities.  All the user-defined values _must_ be [passed via `execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Comment: Currently i am just learning, But thank you for detailing the vulnerability

Comment: "I get very strange result" - what does that mean?

Comment: as in a donnot get a relevant result.

Comment: Order by `MATCH (`title`) AGAINST ('$search') AND (`genre`)` not the `like `matching.. also dont see why `like` matching is needed at all. Actually maybe you just need to full text index the three columns, not just the 1.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I know. I'm going to remove this post. i came in here with no idea what i was doing or what i needed. Admin Please remove if i cant, thank you

Comment: To of used Order by MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$search') AND (genre) Without the AND Genre LIKE $genre, would of returned results where $search MATCHED with `Title` & `Genre` , therfore making the Genre Search Invalid and not searched for.